# MySQL: count rows versus save number of rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, cakephp

I've got a little performance question..

In my db there are three tables: Users, Articles and a join table users_articles (alias likes) for the relationship between them. On a index site i want to display the likes for each article..

currently I save the number of likes in my article table and add or reduce 1 if it changes.

Is it an better approach to count the rows for each article? With every refresh of the index site the db has to count xx rows of xx articles..?

thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the difficulties your current approach is bringing?

Comment: maybe no real difficulties but its more work.. i have to Update that field if a user deletes himself or if a admin deletes him and if for example a user is deleted via phpmyadmin there are mistakes with the Count..  i think its more clean to count them everytime because there are no mistakes then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

1 - you can run the count query every time is needed, so your result is automatically updated (is this a problem for performance? I don't think it should be... Especially if you have an index on the users_articles table on the article id field.)

2 - you can use trigger to update your field on the article table, every time there is a delete, update or insert on users_articles table (is it really difficult for some reasons?)

What to choose is up to you. In the second case is faster when you want the result, in the first one your updates are faster.